# SMB/CIFS fail on boot after power outage. Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, cifs, smb

The other night my breaker tripped and took out the power in my office.  Upon reboot I found that my boot got hung up and it was saying "files/public/" would not mount so I was able to skip or enter manual mode.  When I eventually skipped it I found that SMB/CIFS got a fail

```
* Starting SMB/CIFS File and Active Directory Server                    [fail]

Now I went into log.smbd after restarting and saw some more stuff that was unsuccessful

mbd version 4.1.6-Ubuntu started.
  Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2013
[2014/09/22 17:26:21.668122,  0] ../source3/smbd/server.c:1278(main)
  standard input is not a socket, assuming -D option
[2014/09/22 17:26:22.230303,  0] ../source3/printing/print_cups.c:151(cups_connect)
  Unable to connect to CUPS server localhost:631 - Bad file descriptor
[2014/09/22 17:26:22.230616,  0] ../source3/printing/print_cups.c:528(cups_async_callback)
  failed to retrieve printer list: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
[2014/09/22 17:38:22.659314,  0] ../source3/printing/print_cups.c:151(cups_connect)
  Unable to connect to CUPS server localhost:631 - Bad file descriptor
[2014/09/22 17:38:22.659587,  0] ../source3/printing/print_cups.c:528(cups_async_callback)
  failed to retrieve printer list: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
[2014/09/22 17:51:23.440297,  0] ../source3/printing/print_cups.c:151(cups_connect)
  Unable to connect to CUPS server localhost:631 - Bad file descriptor
[2014/09/22 17:51:23.440554,  0] ../source3/printing/print_cups.c:528(cups_async_callback)
  failed to retrieve printer list: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
[2014/09/22 18:04:24.220946,  0] ../source3/printing/print_cups.c:151(cups_connect)
  Unable to connect to CUPS server localhost:631 - Bad file descriptor
[2014/09/22 18:04:24.221210,  0] ../source3/printing/print_cups.c:528(cups_async_callback)
  failed to retrieve printer list: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
[2014/09/22 18:17:24.946396,  0] ../source3/printing/print_cups.c:151(cups_connect)
  Unable to connect to CUPS server localhost:631 - Bad file descriptor
[2014/09/22 18:17:24.946705,  0] ../source3/printing/print_cups.c:528(cups_async_callback)
  failed to retrieve printer list: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
[2014/09/22 18:30:25.660192,  0] ../source3/printing/print_cups.c:151(cups_connect)
  Unable to connect to CUPS server localhost:631 - Bad file descriptor
[2014/09/22 18:30:25.660459,  0] ../source3/printing/print_cups.c:528(cups_async_callback)
  failed to retrieve printer list: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
[2014/09/22 18:43:26.385341,  0] ../source3/printing/print_cups.c:151(cups_connect)
  Unable to connect to CUPS server localhost:631 - Bad file descriptor
[2014/09/22 18:43:26.385610,  0] ../source3/printing/print_cups.c:528(cups_async_callback)
  failed to retrieve printer list: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
```

Now I actually have no problem accessing or writing to my shares.  The only issue that is slightly annoying is my boot gets hung up and I have to push it along to tell it not to mount that file system.

I can't SSH into anything until I do this.  I have tried several things from this site and have had no luck.  Anything I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

I also have some problems with it (Starting SMB/CIFS File and Active Directory Server [fail]) and log of samba tell me this:

At this time the samba binary should be used for either: 'server role = active directory domain controller' or to access the ntvfs file server with 'server services = +smb' or the rpc proxy with 'dcerpc endpoint servers = remote'. You should start smbd/nmbd/winbindd instead for domain member and standalone file server tasks.

Not sure what's that means, but file share is working. Found an answear here - http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/2345494 Take a look, may be that would help you 2.

Comment: Hi and welcome on AskUbuntu! :-) Note that good answers also provide a t least a short description/summary of what is to do and not just drop a link. If in future that link dies for whatever cause, your answer is useless. It also forces interested people to jump to foreign pages which is not appreciated by many users. Please also visit our help page, especially the article on [How to write a good answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer) and you will soon get some upvotes!